# How do I suppress Visual Studio designer warnings in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, warnings, designer, suppress-warnings

I've got this warning that I can't seem to suppress. It is not a compile time warning because I don't see it in the output window at all nor do I see it on the build machine. However, I don't want developers on my team to be staring at this forever (or until we actually fix the issue). It appears to be a Visual Studio specific warning. I didn't even know those existed.

**Warning Info**

**Description:** This project references an earlier version of SQL Server Compact that has no designer support in this version of Visual Studio. To continue without designer support, download SQL Server Compact 3.5 from the Microsoft Download Center (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229598). To upgrade your assets to SQL Server Compact 4.0 and enable designer support, open the project and use the Add Connection dialog box to create a connection to the database.

**File:**

**Line:** 0

**Column:** 0

**Project:** SQLPackage

Please no one answer "upgrade to SQL Server Compact 4.0". I know I can do that but that's not something I can do right now.

Comment: What version of SQL CE are you using? Have you upgraded to the latest service pack?

Comment: I'm using 3.5. Is there an SP for 3.5 I should be aware of?

Comment: There is a SP2, the link you posted in your question brings you to it. That will allow you to use 3.5 with VS2012, but without designer support. Meaning you won't be able to change anything in it.

Comment: It seems I had already done this. I have followed the link and made sure i'm referencing the dlls requested but the warning remains. The only solution I've found is @ErikEJ 's answer and it is to remove the .sdf from the project. However that is not an option for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the sdf file from the project